# Windows 7 Aero Peek Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: windows-7, aero-peek

Let me preface: Don't think this exact question has been asked/answered. When I tried adding to a related thread, asking for help, my post was deleted within minutes! Not giving me much of a play outside of starting my own question.

Really need help from a Windows Guru! Myself and our IT vendor could not solve it! On 12/10 my Windows toolbar suddenly changed to Classic/XP view, but a restart fixed it. Then on 12/18 or 19 my Alt-Tab changed to "classic" view and I don't like it nor can I revert it back to Aero!

System > Advanced > Performance Settings - "Aero Peek" "Desktop Comp" all still on. Tried Task Bar "preview desktop with Aero Peek" still checked. IT even tried creating the "classic" Alt-Tab entry into the Registry, restart, then deleting, logging off/on and still there. I'm somewhat clueless. Obviously using an "Aero" theme because Aero Peek in toolbar is still working. Looked into color profiles (currently 32bit True Color) Did a driver query today and found 2 strange drivers installed on 12/17. Maybe the culprits?  **amdkmdag** and **amdkmdap** 
Anyone have some knowledge on this issue?

Comment: Welcome on Superuser. Asking your own question is the correct action. Amdkmdap and Amdkmdag are generic driver names from ATI/AMD. Try completely wiping your graphics driver and reinstalling them.

Comment: Thank you @NordlysJeger. It is a work PC so can't always do everything myself. However IT vendor tried updating graphics card drivers and also did an SFC scan but neither worked.  Also tried forcing it with AltTabSettings=0 in registry.  At this point they seem to be out ideas, and his only idea now is re-install Windows.  Question, the wipe you mentioned above, I would do that through AMD software correct?  AMD Radeon R9 270 is my card.